# Can I do a pivot chart on Sharepoint, from a list with ~1M entries? And will it perform ok?

Tags: pivot-tables

as mentionned above I would like to have a pivot chart, or a pivot table, on Sharepoint accessing ~1M rows, with up to 100 variables. I'm a beginner with Sharepoint and I'm not aware if it would perform correctly. Presently, we host excel files that users download and run the pivot tables on their own computer instead.

Also, will multiple users be able to access the pivot chart/table separately at the same time?
Does the data need to be stored as a list on sharepoint, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list item limit in SharePoint online is 30 million. You will however, face issues sorting and filtrering the list due to the list view threshold which is 5000 items.

If you want to go with the SharePoint approach I recommend that you are fully aware of the limitations.

For reporting I would look into connecting PowerBI with the list and not rely on excel exports.

That being said, I would not use SharePoint but rather a SQL database for this.

Comment: PowerBI does look quite like what I was looking for! A page where people can come and consult data without any hassle basically. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to SharePoint as well, but might be able to help here.
I'm fairly sure that lists can store 5 million items (rows).  And i don't think a  pivot chart is required, as you can sort all items by multiple fields in the headings which would provide a similar functionality.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It appears fhsp's suggestion is really what I was looking for. Going for a pivot table / chart was gonna be hard, but it was the only solution I was aware. Cheers.